# Convert lock to async in C#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, locking, async-await

How can I convert this singleton method to its equivalent with `async`? I am trying to write something like this: `public static async Task<DbContext> DBContext`.

```
public class ModelDB
{
    static DbContext _dbContext;
    readonly static object obj = new object();

    public static DbContext DBContext
    {
        get
        {
            lock (obj)
            {
                if (_dbContext == null)
                {
                    _dbContext = new MoviesDBEntities();
                }

                return _dbContext;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: eee, `lock` and `async` are completely different things from completely different concepts: asynchronous and parallel programming.

Comment: You don't have any asynchronous work to do.  Also, a static DbContext is a generally a bad idea.

Comment: Note, that you cannot use an EF context concurrently anyway. Probably this question is moot considering this.

Comment: @usr. Can you explain me why I cannot use an EF context concurrently?

Comment: @SLaks Can you tell me why is a bad idea to put my DBContext as a Singleton?

Comment: @Zinov it's the other way round. By default nothing is thread-safe. You must have a good reason to believe that it is. EF does not guarantee thread-safety.

Comment: @Zinov: DbContexts cannot be used concurrently, and hold a DB connection while active.  You should create them locally and dispose them ASAP.

Comment: @SLaks but there is not a performance issue while you create a new DBContext every time you want to use it? In my experience, the general idea is keeping alive just one instead of creating multiples, if you have a concurrent scenario, imagine having 1000 clients making a simple request to see the data of a grid on a webapplication and you creating 1000 instances of the same dbcontext. Can you tell me the best way, maybe recommend an article to read?

Comment: @Zinov Would you rather have code that doesn't perform well, or code that just doesn't work at all?  "Performance Improvements" are only *actually* performance improvements when they still work.  That said, no, creating new contexts is not going to be particularly expensive.  Creating 1000 contexts when you get 1000 requests is not likely to be a problem at all.

Comment: Stop editing your title to have something radically different from what the actual question is asking.  If you have a new question that you want to ask, then ask a new question, don't change a 3 year old question to have a title that is quite different from what it's actually asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can (and probably should) still use a synchronous `lock` even while inside an `async` method unless you expect the `lock` to be held longer than usual (I guess `new MoviesDBEntities();` shouldn't really take more than a few milliseconds).

When you actually need asynchronous locking you can use `SemaphoreSlim` set to 1 and call `WaitAsync` to wait asynchronously like this:

```
await _semphore.WaitAsync()
try
{
    ... use shared resource.
}
finally
{
    _semphore.Release()
}
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21011273/885318) an implementation example.

Comment: @Zinov after almost 3 years? Don't you think you should ask a new one?

Comment: fixing the question instead to bring more details, I already got my answer back then