# Design: Task B to pause Task A temporarily to take care of work, and then restart Task A

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-await

I can't figure out how to do this in a good way.

Basically, I have a program with two key tasks that contain loops that it runs over and over until the user clicks the stop button.

Pseudo code:

1. Task A is started: a while loop that does work continuously
2. Task B is started: a `System.Timers.Timer` that checks continuously
   for a specific condition
3. If Task B finds the condition to be true, it should temporarily stop Task A, and do a bunch of work
4. Once Task B is done with that work it should allow Task A to start looping again, and go back to checking for the specific condition

This then all continues in perpetuity (until user clicks stop button and the program ends).

When I made the first iteration of the program I basically created two separate threads, and then just had bools in the loops that i used for cancellation. So, Task B just set the bool in Task A to be false and used a `Thread.Join()` to wait until Task A had completely finished before it started doing its work. Once Task B was done, it created Task A on a completely new thread again. This seemed highly inefficient, as there is no reason I should really have to end the thread, when all I want to do is just halt it until Task B is done.

I have been reading up on `async` ops through Task Parallel Library (`async-await`), and thought I could perhaps use cancellation tokens instead of the bools, but it looks like once a task is cancelled with cancellation token the token cannot be reset and task cannot be restarted.

In any case, how would you build this?

Comment: Use synchronization mechanisms like Mutex, ManuallyResetEvent, Semaphore etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object to be used for locking. Put the working part of both task A and B inside a lock statement on this object. Make sure you lock inside the loop of thread A, so that you give B a chance to acquire the lock too, between iterations. This way, only one thread may enter the locked region at a time. Thread A doesn't have to be stopped, it will continue running when B is finished. (You could also use wait handles, or mutexes, or whatever really, it's the most basic case of mutual exclusion.)

Comment: Thanks guys. Fejesjoco, is that similar to @L.B's suggestion? Are these types of classes/patterns obsolete now that Task asynchrony is out there? I am a bit confuised as someone once told me that a lot of the original threading is now outdated with all the new task asynchronous functionality out there...

Comment: Forgot to ask: 1) Would you use Tasks instead of Threads for any of this? 2) Would you use cancellation tokens to cancel the loops in the threads/tasks, once the user clicks stop button? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364.aspx)

Comment: I wouldn't use tasks for continuously running jobs, threads are perfect for that, but that's just an opinion. Unless a .NET class is officially obsoleted, there's nothing wrong with using it under the right circumstances. Cancellation tokens are perfect for stopping threads.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot. I could mark the task as longrunning to avoid using the thread pool, but i def have to look into regular mutual exclusion, as I jumped straight to asynchronous programming before really learning old school threading first...

Comment: @fejesjoco: this would be a good answer, worthy of an up-vote, except for two problems: you didn't show any code example, and the statement that the object reference should be `static`. Just as a question should include a code example, so too should an answer (even if the question failed to). And whether the locking object should be referenced by a `static` field or not depends entirely on whether the code that uses it is `static` or not (which we don't know here).

Comment: @PeterDuniho I removed the static part, that was just out of habit/experience, but I don't understand your other comment. He asked a theoretical question, I gave a theoretical answer. I suggested the lock keyword exactly because it's so simple and it's part of the C# syntax. I really wonder what added value would it have, just typing a keyword? OP obviously knows enough not to need that. How could I provide a meaningful example if there was no code in the question? I'm totally confused why you would mention it.

Comment: Sorry if my suggestion isn't clear. My point is this: your answer takes the form of describing how one would write some code. But _actual code_ is a much better way to express something like that. Even if the code is simple and can't include specific details of the actual operations (since the OP failed to provide those), a code example is far more useful and less ambiguous than an English-language description of that code.

Answer (score 1):

To do that in a truly `async-await` fashion you shouldn't block threads or have them in a state of busy-wait (looping constantly until some condition changes) because it's synchronous and wastes resources. You should use `async` synchronization objects.

In your case you can have an `AsyncLock` to handle the mutually exclusive part (making sure only one worker runs at the same time) and an `AsyncAutoResetEvent` to notify the second worker of the condition change.

Unfortunately the .Net Framework doesn't yet have a built-in implementation for `AsyncLock` or `AsyncAutoResetEvent`, but the [Visual Studio SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.threading.aspx) does (or you can implement them yourself, [like I did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21011273/885318)).

Comment: Thanks l3arnon, I will look into this once I have successfully implemented the blocking approach. To avoid the spinner (looping until condition change), I am using a Timer. That is pretty efficient. The other loops do work in each loop.