# Mutex that not block current(UI) thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have one little task - i have to create mutex,using tasks and async\await,that not blocking current thread(UI thread).

**Mutex interface:**

Lock() – returns a Task, wich will be completed only when mutex will become free. This task must be 
unique per lock to disallow more than 1 unblock per Release() call.
Release() – release mutex. One and only one of tasks, returned by Lock(), must become completed.
That mutex have to work in a such way

```
await mutex.Lock();
// critical code  
mutex.Release();
```

I wrote some piece of code(see link in the end),but if briefly describe the problem is:
I create a class Mutex.
In the method Lock i do something like that:

```
await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    mutex.WaitOne();
    UserDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
});
```

In the method Release i do something like that:

```
if (mutex != null && UserDispatcher != null)
{
    UserDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Releasing");
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
    }));
}
```

When i`m trying release mutex,my program just freeze forever. What the problem?

Full code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4a370cn1bd2o0nz/MainWindow.xaml.cs?dl=0

Link to project: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qsgle79jdgpr7cd/AAA3MZ6VlTNbUj-isgaQaLE-a?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have a deadlock on your hands when the UI thread is stuck waiting for the mutex to be released on `mutex.WaitOne();` and you're trying to release it using the same UI thread (which is blocked) by posting the `mutex.ReleaseMutex();` on it using the dispatcher.

If you want an `async` mutex you can simply use a `SemaphoreSlim` set to 1 (hence, mutual exclusion) and call `WaitAsync` to wait asynchronously.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21011273/885318)'s my implementation of an `AsyncLock` (which is the same as an async mutex) using `SemaphoreSlim`.

Comment: A little problem here... My Mutex have to work in a such way `await mutex.Lock();` , i can`t do that with semaphore(

Comment: @progerz you can with `SemaphoreSlim` and `WaitAsync`.

Comment: @i3aron and it will be work in a such way? Have you Skype or another messenger? I have few liitle questions about that.

Comment: @progerz It will. You have a full example in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21011273/885318. It's better if you ask there if you have issues since it will be visible to everybody.