# async await async all the way

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task-parallel-library, wait

I'm new to c# async await mechanism. I read some articles about async all the way (http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). I have an example below, could you please let me know if the first `Initialize` method will cause dead lock and why? Thank you in advance.

```
public class Test {

    public  async  Task DoSomeWorkAsync() {
      await DoSomeWork1Async(); 
    }

    // This method is mixed with Wait and async await, will this cause lead lock?
    public void Initialize() {
      Task.Run(() => DoSomeWorkAsync()).Wait();
    }

    // This method is following async all the way
    public async Task InitializeAsync()  {
      await DoSomeWorkAsync();
    }

}

// Update: Here is the context where two Initialize methods are called
public class TestForm : Form {
  // Load Form UI
  public async void OnLoad() {
    var test = new Test();
    test.Initialize();
    await test.InitializeAsync();
  }
}
```

Comment: It depends on context where you are using it.

Comment: In the `Initialize()` method, I would simply do `DoSomeWorkAsync().Wait()`. Using `Task.Run()` will start a new thread and call DoSomeWorkAsync() synchronously.

Comment: thanks guys I added context where they are being used.

Comment: @PhilippeParé: thx Philippe, but will DoSomeWorkAsync().Wait() cause dead lock? I assume async-await all the way down means once you use asyn-await, you can't mix Wait(). Please Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You can certainly use Wait() on a Task, it will simply be executed synchronously. If by "dead lock" you mean a UI thread block, then yes, Wait() will block the UI thread but only for the execution of the method.

Comment: @PhilippeParé no. It will deadlock as in it will get stuck forever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this will not deadlock because you're blocking on a task that's being **executed by a `ThreadPool` thread with no `SynchronizationContext`**. Since it isn't running on the UI thread there's nothing stopping that task from completing and so there's no deadlock.

If this was your code, it will have deadlocked:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    DoSomeWorkAsync().Wait();
}
```

This is still not a good reason to block though, you should use async-await all they way up.

Comment: @i3amon: thx i3amon. The reason I wanna use Initialize() over InitializeAsync() is because class TestForm has a lock object, which prevent OnLoad method being called concurrently, which looks like this: lock(lockObj) {Initialize(); } However await InitializeAsync(); could not be called within lock statement.

Comment: @macio.Jun then use an [AsyncLock](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21011273/885318) instead

Comment: @macio.Jun sure.. any time.

Comment: @i3amon, sorry I have one more unclear point. Is there a difference between Initialize method above and public void Initialize() {Task.Run(async() => await DoSomeWorkAsync()).Wait();} ?

Comment: @macio.Jun not really, the `async` and `await` are redundant.