How to properly handle double-clicking the back button in .net MAUI?
I have a main page:
MainPage : ContentPage


There are also pages that I navigate to using
await Navigation.PushModalAsync(NewPage);


When I have several pages in my stack and I press the Back button twice, the application freezes and the screen has a white background.
Can someone tell me which way to dig the problem?
I assume that the problem here is related to asynchronous calls, but I do not know where to wait for the shutdown.

Do you mean the browser back button or a button on your application/web page?

Are you describing a reentrant problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35419752/reentrancy-in-async-await

No web page.
Here example and demo
https://github.com/shm0nya/Sample-double-click-maui-error

I open issue on maui repo. Waiting solution
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/26617

Thanks for your support and feedback for Maui. :)
