# Is it possible to read the state of the serial port? If it is currently in use or not?

Tags: uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I'm currently writung a Win Iot app for the Raspberry Pi and I'm currently encountering some problems...

The problem I want to ask here is that I have multiple commands that I have to send out over the serial port (RS485) and I will also get a response in return.
But whenever I accidently invoke the send command twice or somehow my app is doing nothing (it's doing something but I don't know what...sadly) and I press the send button again then my app crashes.

Now I want to ask if there is a method to get the current state of the serial port somehow?
I wnat to know if the port is used for sending/recieving at the moment and if it is I want to block my command from being sent until the current operation is done. Or it should just give an error like "I'm busy. Try again later!".

I would really appreciate the help because I don't know how to do that :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.open(v=vs.110).aspx

A serial port can only be opened once. If it's already open you, and you try to open it a second time, you should get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` exception, which you should handle. You could interpret this as another command operation still being in progress.

If you have a single com port instance, and are sharing that instance between the commands, you should pend on some kind of locking mechanism in order to protect the comport. E.g. take a [semaphoreslim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011179/how-to-protect-resources-that-may-be-used-in-a-multi-threaded-or-async-environme) initialized to `1`, and when you'd like to use the comport, wait on the semaphore. When you're done, release the semaphore. This way, only one command will use the stream simultaneously.

Comment: Ok this really did the job of blocking other commands to use the port while one is already using it. That directly solved another problem I had where I had to fire two commands directly in a row because I needed both results. So thanks for your help :)
The only problem now is that my app crashes when I fire the third command...I put every command into a try/catch block but that doesnt prevent it from crashing...